# Unity Camera Rotate Around Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project I currently have 1 script, 1 camera, and 1 object. I wrote a code (see below) that  will rotate the camera around the object but X axis is not always left and right, and Y axis is not always up and down.

What I mean by this is, if for example, we load into unity with the camera axis being Y = up, X = left, Z being forward as the transform position and the object having the same orientation as the camera. I can click and drag left or right/ up or down and the camera will rotate with it correctly, but as soon as I rotate it 90 DEG any direction, the opposite axis will not rotate as I want it to.

I know there is a term for this "perfect rotation" but I do not know the term , thus it is very difficult for me to explain. Sorry. Please feel free to enter the code into a C# script and play around with it. add the script to the camera, make sure the camera is looking at the object, and the object needs to be added to the gameobject on the script.

can someone please help me so that when I swipe left, the object will always rotate left, right for right, up for up and down for down.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FocusObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject target;//the target object
    private Vector3 point;//the coord to the point where the camera looks at

    float f_lastX = 0.0f;
    float f_difX = 0.0f;  
    float f_lastY = 0.0f;
    float f_difY = 0.0f;  


    void Start()
    {//Set up things on the start method
        point = target.transform.position;//get target's coords
        transform.LookAt(point);//makes the camera look to it 
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            f_difX = 0.0f;
            f_difY = 0.0f;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            f_difX = Mathf.Abs(f_lastX - Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
            f_difY = Mathf.Abs(f_lastY - Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

            if (f_lastX < Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"))
            {
                transform.RotateAround(point, new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), f_difX);
            }

            if (f_lastX > Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"))
            {
                transform.RotateAround(point, new Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), f_difX);
            }

            if (f_lastY < Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"))
            {
                transform.RotateAround(point, new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), f_difY);
            }

            if (f_lastY > Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"))
            {
                transform.RotateAround(point, new Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), f_difY);

            }

            f_lastX = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            f_lastY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Found the answer I was looking for see link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030524/unity-object-not-rotating-around-correct-axis?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity object not rotating around correct axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030524/unity-object-not-rotating-around-correct-axis)